# dismissViewControllerAnimated and unintended tableview repositioning

Tags: iphone

I currently have a UIViewController with UIView inside it, that is changed via tabbar. The problem is illustrated in the following images:

1. Loading the table (normal):

   [image]
2. After selecting a row, empty placeholder appears (normal):

   [image: selecting a row, empty placeholder (normal)]
3. After pressing return and calling the dismissViewControllerAnimated:completed: method (problem):

   [image: calling the dismissViewControllerAnimated:completed method (problem)]

It seems that when I dismiss the view, it ignores my tabbar items and forgets the positioning, relocating the table all the way at the top, underneath my menu. Is there something that I can do to correct this?

---

The Code:

(in MainViewController):

```
[self presentViewController:collectionController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

(in CollectionViewController):

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way to resolve the tableview repositioning, but since it ignores the viewDidLoad: method, I found a work-around.

I added a 50px header to the tableview and in viewDidLoad:, I repositioned the view to be 50px higher:

```
 tableView.frame = CGRectOffset(tableView.frame, 0, -50);
```

It now displays 'correctly', but the scrollbar for the table is cropped off by the tabbar items.